# How to control orientation/twist of Skin Modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Is there any way to control the twist (for lack of a better term) of a skin modifier?

Here are three different versions of the same initial mesh with Skin Modifiers applied. The only difference in each of these is where the Root of the modifier is located.

[image]

As you can see, each version has a different orientation for the square profile of the resulting mesh. And when the root is placed in the middle, the beam appears to twist halfway through.

In short, is there any way to achieve an orientation like that highlighted green such that it doesn't twist halfway through?

Is there an entirely better approach to procedurally generating beams from isolated edge loops? I know you can do something with curves, but wouldn't you have the same 'twist' problem there?

[image]

Comment: Hello, you should mention that your beams are tilted along the XZ plane, which changes the vertex normals thus changing the intial rotation of the root vertex. Try scaling everything 0 along Z and applying a simple deform set to bend along the Y axis